# Optimizing a function

Tags: python, optimization, timeit

I've come up with a problem:

I am writing a function that accepts 2 arguments: `rug_length` and `prices`, `rug_length` is an int representing how many meters of a rug you want to buy, `prices` is a dictionary that holds prices for a different length of a rug where key is the length and the value is the price.

An example of a function call:

```
rug_length = 10
prices = {1:2, 2:3, 3:1, 4:5, 5:4}

fn(rug_length, prices)
```

The function needs to return the minimum cost of a selected length of the rug, so for example:

```
fn(1, prices) # returns 2
fn(3, prices) # returns 1
fn(5, prices) # returns 4
fn(6, prices) # returns 2 ( 1 + 1 )
fn(8, prices) # returns 5 ( 1 + 1 + 2 )
fn(9, prices) # returns 3 ( 3 + 3 + 3 )
```

I figured I sort the dictionary by the cost of a meter.

I've written two functions:

```
def fn(rug_length, prices):
    if rug_length == 0:
        return 0
    cost = 0
    while rug_length > 0:
        for key, v in sorted(prices.items(), key=(lambda item : (item[1]/item[0]))):
            while rug_length >= key:
                rug_length -= key
                cost += prices[key]
    return cost

%%timeit -n 250
fn(245245, price)
# 4.54 ms ± 25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 250 loops each)
```

And the second one:

```
def fn_2(rug_length, prices):
    if rug_length == 0:
        return 0
    cost = 0
    prices = sorted(prices.items(), key=(lambda item : (item[1]/item[0])))
    while rug_length > 0:
        for key,v in prices:
            cost += (rug_length//key)*v
            rug_length%=key
    return cost

%%timeit -n 250
fn_2(245245, price)
# 1.76 µs ± 54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 250 loops each)
```

Is there a place for improvement?

Comment: Why do you care about optimizing something which takes less than two microseconds? If the prices don't change much you could keep the sorted list in memory.

Comment: For example if I try to buy a rug of length 10^7 the computation takes more time, I am wondering if there is a code which I cant change that would run faster.